# Custom attribute update & value added/stored on save

Tags: php, magento-1, attributes, event-observer, product-attribute

I'm trying to store the sum of two attributes into a new custom field on save. One is just price, and the other one is a custom price attribute field called customtext. So when there's a value in the customtext field, it should add up both price and the value from that field and display it in the 'customprice'field in the backend. I'm kind of stuck, so I was hoping someone could take a look at what I have so far.

My config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
            <class>Namespace_AttributeUpdate_Model</class>
        </Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
    </models>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
                    <class>Namespace_AttributeUpdate/observer</class>
                    <method>updateAttribute</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

And my observer:

```
<?php

class Namespace_AttributeUpdate_Model_Observer extends  Varien_Event_Observer

{
public function updateAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $customtext = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('customtext');
    $priceWithText = $price + $customtext;
    $product->setData('price_inctext', $priceWithText);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are not save the set value yet in your observer

Comment: so I should add $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'customtext'); after retrieving and before I move on ?

Comment: Did your observer reached the desired function once you saved the product?

Comment: Hope you have closoing </config> tag as well. Just like @mujas said, make sure if your observer is being called or not.

Comment: Yes the closing config tag is there :) didn't copy and paste it right, sorry

Comment: I hope you can't reach the updateAttribute() method in the observer.Because  in your config method is look like this <method>incTextUpdate</method>

Comment: You're right, I totally missed that. Thanks. However, after adjusting the method it's still not outputting the desired results

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your observer is not called because the `<method>` in the config.xml and the observer method `updateAttribute` are not same.
You want to update your config file like below.

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_save_before>
        <observers>
            <Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
                <class>Namespace_AttributeUpdate/observer</class>
                <method>updateAttribute</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </Namespace_AttributeUpdate>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_before>
</events>
```

and in the **observer.php** add the following line.

```
<?php
class Namespace_AttributeUpdate_Model_Observer extends  Varien_Event_Observer
{
  public function updateAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $customtext = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('customtext');
    $priceWithText = $price + $customtext;
    //$product->setData('price_inctext', $priceWithText);
    //Newly added line for update price_inctext
    $product->setData('price_inctext', $priceWithText)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price_inctext');
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code and did it exactly as you mentioned and the event seems to be firing, but now it throws a 500 server error

Comment: What is customtext and price_inctext?

Comment: customtext is a price attribute field where I store the value manually that after save needs to be stored in price_inctext, so a sum of the customtext value + the regular price field

Comment: I guess price_inctext also an attribute right? If yes did you created that attribute also from admin panel?

Comment: yes that is correct, and yes I manually created that from the admin.

Comment: You retrive the value of $customtext = $_product->, This is wrong you want to retrieve the value like this $customtext = $product-> .Check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33514/discussion-between-mujas-and-simone).